# get Mondays between two dates mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I want to get the Mondays between two dates with a select statement, but I only have searched in sql server.

I have tried this, but it doesn´t work:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY) AS Date 
FROM (
            SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row 
            FROM (
                        SELECT 0 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 6
            ) t1,
            (
                SELECT 0 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 6
            ) t2, 
            (
                SELECT @row:=-1
            ) t3 LIMIT 31
        ) b
WHERE DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
AND DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY)) = 2
```

This query only gives me the Monday´s date for one month.

I hope that you can help me

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to solve this SQL only, you have to delve a bit deeper and generate a sequence of days, this is by far the most difficult side task to solve this. Besides this, as you have already guessed, you can use [`DAYOFWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) or [`WEEKDAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) to get your desired days.

```
SELECT  * 
   FROM (
        SELECT  DATE_ADD('2013-01-01', 
            INTERVAL n4.num*1000+n3.num*100+n2.num*10+n1.num DAY ) AS DATE 
          FROM  (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
         ) AS n1,
         (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
        ) AS n2,
        (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
        ) AS n3,
        (
              SELECT 0 AS num
              UNION ALL SELECT 1
              UNION ALL SELECT 2
              UNION ALL SELECT 3
              UNION ALL SELECT 4
              UNION ALL SELECT 5
              UNION ALL SELECT 6
              UNION ALL SELECT 7
              UNION ALL SELECT 8
              UNION ALL SELECT 9
        ) AS n4
    ) AS a
WHERE DATE >= '2017-01-01' AND DATE < NOW()
  AND WEEKDAY(DATE) = 0
ORDER BY DATE
```

Some other RDBMS have inbuild functions for that.

If would be way easier if you have a calendar table where all dates are already present.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this solution will work with better performance than previous

```
SET @date_start = date('2019-07-06');
SET @date_end = date('2019-09-18');

SELECT CASE WHEN MOD(DAYOFWEEK(@date_start), 7) <= 2 AND
      MOD(DAYOFWEEK(@date_start), 7) + DATEDIFF(v.selected_date, @date_start) - 7 * FLOOR(DATEDIFF(v.selected_date, @date_start) / 7) >= 2 OR
      MOD(DAYOFWEEK(@date_start), 7) > 2 AND
      MOD(DAYOFWEEK(@date_start), 7) + DATEDIFF(v.selected_date, @date_start) - 7 * FLOOR(DATEDIFF(v.selected_date, @date_start) / 7) >= 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  + FLOOR(DATEDIFF(v.selected_date, @date_start) / 7) num_of_mo
 ,  @date_start start_date,v.selected_date end_date
FROM (select adddate(@date_start,t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
WHERE v.selected_date <= @date_end;
```